# How to reverse Date.parse()

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My code:

```
require 'Date'

s = "I'm going away on Oct 2, 2012th"
puts Date.parse(s)

=> 2012-10-02
```

I want to delete the date from my strings, that I found with `Date.parse(s)`. The problem is, I know that there is a date, but not how it was written in the string. I know that `Date.parse` found it and converted "2012-10-02" to a new format.

Comment: The `parse` method discards everything except a valid date. Since you don't know the format or length you'd have to test every possible set of characters within the string. Not very pretty. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty solution.  The function `date_string`
returns just the portion of the string containing the date
found by `parse`.

```
require 'date'

DATE_ERROR = -1

# If the string doesn't contain a date, it raises an
# exception.  This little helper routine catches the
# exception.
def get_date(s)
    date = 0
    begin
        date = Date.parse(s)
    rescue
        date = DATE_ERROR
    end
    date
end

# Returns just the part of the string containing the date
def date_string(s)
    # First, find the date contained in the string
    date = get_date(s)

    return "" if date == DATE_ERROR

    # Repeatedly chop off characters from the front to find the
    # start of the date
    first = 1
    while date == get_date(s[first..-1])
        first += 1
    end

    # Repeatedly chop off characters from the end to find the
    # end of the date
    last = s.length - 2
    while date == get_date(s[0..last])
        last -= 1
    end

    #Return just the date
    s[first - 1..last + 1]
end

puts date_string("I'm going away on Oct 2, 2012th")
puts date_string("I'm going away on 10/2/12 and not coming back")
puts date_string("10 Nov 1999")
puts date_string("I see no date here")
```

This outputs:

```
Oct 2, 2012
10/2/12
10 Nov 1999
```

So you could do something like:

```
s = "I'm going away on Oct 2, 2012th"
datestr = date_string(s)
s.gsub!(datestr, "")
puts s
```

Answer (score 0):

`Date` doesn't appear to be able to tell you where it found the date. You're probably going to have to write your own custom date finder.